# Getting time of day of bar close

Tags: pine-script

I would like to see if the bar close is 8am UTC (for every bar in a strategy) in pinescript.

I figure I can maybe use time_close (although that may not be dynamic). Since this returns a unix timestamp I am a bit at a loss on how to test if the close price was at 8amUTC or not. First step would be to extract time of day from the unix timestamp...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the built-in variable 'hour', which returns the closing hour of the current bar.

Answer (score 1):

The [hour()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_hour) function can accept time:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
study("My Script")
plot(hour(time_close))
```